# elisp - construct a quasi-alist from variable

Tags: quote, association-lists, backquote

To construct a quasi-alist, case 1 is using hardcode string; case 2 is using a variable `filename` to replace the hadcode string. but case 2 doesn't work as expected (should the same as case 1).

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
;; case 1
(setq alist '((:file . "test.txt")))
(print alist)

;;case 2
(setq filename "test.txt")
(setq alist '((:file . filename)))
(print alist)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: ((:file . "test.txt"))
: 
: ((:file . filename))
```

What's the right way to use a variable to construct a quasi-alist?

Comment: Backquote/quasiquote the list, and use a comma to unquote the cdr.

Comment: In case 2 you have `quote`d the form, which means no part of the form is evaluated. Hence `filename` remains a symbol. See `C-h i g (elisp) Backquote`